# Does the back propagation for a FC network change when there's a dropout layer involved?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have a fairly simple neural network - input layer, hidden layer, output layer. It's a fully connected (FC) neural network. I'm using a fairly standard gradient backpropagation. I'm wondering if I add a dropout layer to make the network input layer -> dropout layer -> hidden layer -> output layer, if I need to factor in the deletion layer into my backpropagation algorithm.

I can see it in two different ways:

1) It's random, so don't touch it
2) If I don't touch it, my final results will be exactly the same as if I didn't have a deletion layer.

So what's the proper way to handle a dropout layer when training a NN? Do I just not adjust the neurons that got deleted?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "deletion layer" in standard NN terminology. Do you possibly mean a dropout layer? Please clarify...

Comment: With some quick googling - yes, dropout layer

Comment: Still, your question is way too broad. What exactly do you mean "to handle"? Are you building this manually, or are you using some framework (e.g. Keras, Tensorflow etc)? Certainly, the presence of dropout layer(s) affects the mechanics of backpropagation, both in the forward and in the backward pass...

Comment: I found the answer! Dropout backprop
During the backprop, what we need to do is just to consider the Dropout. The killed neurons don’t contribute anything to the network, so we won’t flow the gradient through them.

dh1 *= u1
For full example, please refer to: https://github.com/wiseodd/hipsternet/blob/master/hipsternet/neuralnet.py.

Comment: Good for you; now, either share it with us here as an answer to your own question, or kindly delete this post...

Comment: sorry @desertnaut - I hit enter to create some space in my answer, forgetting that comments will automatically post when you hit enter. It's been edited and responded to below. Thank you for your terminology help, that was exactly what I needed to be able to find the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here: https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2016/06/25/dropout/

" Dropout backprop
During the backprop, what we need to do is just to consider the Dropout. The killed neurons don’t contribute anything to the network, so we won’t flow the gradient through them.

dh1 *= u1
For full example, please refer to: https://github.com/wiseodd/hipsternet/blob/master/hipsternet/neuralnet.py."

In other words, dead neurons aren't contributing, so when we're back propagating, we don't adjust them.